# Tire size (53-584) but different widths

Tags: mountain-bike, rims, compatibility

Hello and thanks for being here!

Can one put 27.5"×2.10 tires (53-584) bicycle tires on the same rims which now have 27.5×1.95 (53-584) on them?

This is the One I have : [code]https://www.mongoose.com/products/excursion-27-5 [/code] with the 27.5" x 1.95(53-584) Tires. The pic is what I want to put on it if possible...[image]

Comment: Rims, yes. Frame, maybe.

Comment: If they're both 53-584 they're not different sizes (except perhaps for tread thickness).

Comment: Both inch and ETRTO measurements specify diameter and width. So, at least one of these measurements must be wrong.

Comment: 54-584 would be the 27.5 * 2.10  50-584 would be 27.5 * 2.00.                      47-584 would be 27.5 * 1.75

Comment: Understand that measuring tire width is a black art.  Generally speaking, there is a roughly 30% range in the width of a tire that will fit a specific rim, and the stated width of the tire might vary based on the rim it was measured on, the thickness of the tread, and other factors.